# left-closed Interval of dates unexpected, query using NHIBERNATE

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a method in a DAL class:

```
public IList<HouseHold> FindByDate(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.AbreSession())
    {
        return session.CreateCriteria<HouseHold>()
            .Add(Expression.Between("RegistrationDate", start, end))
            .List<HouseHold>();
    }
}
```

With this, I expected to get data from dates between a closed interval. But when I use this method and it the result is a left-closed interval, like this:

```
private IList<HouseHold> LoadData()
{
    hh = dao.FindByDate(start.SelectedDate.Value, end.SelectedDate.Value);
    return hh;
}
```

I choose dates between 20/08/2015 and 22/08/2015 from `DataPicker` (WPF), it shows results from 20 to 21. But When I choose dates 20/08/2015 and 23/08/2015 it shows results from 20 to 22, while I know that are results from 23!

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems we have to convert morning time to midnight time. I.e from
`23/08/2015 00:00` - we need `23/08/2015 23:59`

The most simple way would be just to add a day

```
.Add(Expression.Between("RegistrationDate", start, end.AddDay(1)))
```

Comment: Except if the "between" is actually inclusive, you don't want to include values precisely at midnight on the end+1 date... so you may want `end.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1)`.

Comment: Exactly.. I wanted to point out, that there is a **time** issue not NHibernate